# why isn't the try again option not working in this code?

Tags: python

```
import random

stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']

try_again = True
end_of_game = False
word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

while try_again:
    chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
    word_length = len(chosen_word)

    display = []
    for _ in range(word_length):
        display += "_"
    lives = 6
    while not end_of_game:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        for position in range(word_length):
            letter = chosen_word[position]
            if letter == guess:
                display[position] = letter

        if guess not in chosen_word:
            lives = lives - 1
            if lives == 0:
                end_of_game = True
                print("You lose, try again or quit")


        print(f"{' '.join(display)}")

        if "_" not in display:
            end_of_game = True
            print("You win.")
        print(stages[lives])

        if lives == 0:
            x = input("Do you want to try again? (y/n):\n")
            if x == "y":
                try_again = True
            else:
                try_again = False
```

I created this hangman game while watching a tutorial, it didn't include any option of trying again once we lose so I tried to create one.
When I press "y" and enter nothing really happens, the output console is just blank.
Can someone please explain what is wrong with this code?
I also tried to put the if statement in the `lives == 0` loop but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Did you press the enter key after `y`?

Comment: Seems it will ask the question every turn but if the game hasn't ended continue the game. You probably want to un-indent the if statement to be outside the ` while not end_of_game` loop

Comment: You need to reset `end_of_game`   if you want a new game. Otherwise you enter infinite loop `while try_again:` - you never enter `while not end_of_game:`

Comment: put the game as a function and the try again as return und do the while over the function

Comment: @mousetail, it will ask only when lives=0

Comment: thankyou for all the answers, there were 2 problems here, first was that i did not reinitialize value of lives to 6 and second I did not change the end_of_lives variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing end_of_game to true if the player use all of is trial so when pressing y you will never enter in the second while. The number of lives must be also re-updated to 6 so the player can play again:

```
import random

stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']

try_again = True
end_of_game = False
word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

while try_again:
    chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
    word_length = len(chosen_word)

    display = []
    for _ in range(word_length):
        display += "_"
    lives = 6
    while not end_of_game:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        for position in range(word_length):
            letter = chosen_word[position]
            if letter == guess:
                display[position] = letter

        if guess not in chosen_word:
            lives = lives - 1
            if lives == 0:
                end_of_game = False
                lives = 6
                print("You lose, try again or quit")


        print(f"{' '.join(display)}")

        if "_" not in display:
            end_of_game = True
            print("You win.")
        print(stages[lives])

        if lives == 0:
            x = input("Do you want to try again? (y/n):\n")
            if x == "y":
                try_again = True

            else:
                try_again = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Back this 'if' loop out to the level of 'while not end_of_game' (first indent level) and add line for 'end of game = False'.

```
if lives == 0:
    x = input("Do you want to try again? (y/n):\n")
    if x == "y":
        end_of_game = False
        try_again = True
        
    else:
        try_again = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import random
    
stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']

try_again = True

word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
def game():
    chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
    word_length = len(chosen_word)
    end_of_game = False
    display = []
    for _ in range(word_length):
        display += "_"
    lives = 6
    while not end_of_game:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        for position in range(word_length):
            letter = chosen_word[position]
            if letter == guess:
                display[position] = letter

        if guess not in chosen_word:
            lives = lives - 1
            if lives == 0:
                end_of_game = True
                print("You lose, try again or quit")

        print(f"{' '.join(display)}")

        if "_" not in display:
            end_of_game = True
            print("You win.")
        print(stages[lives])

        if lives == 0:
            x = input("Do you want to try again? (y/n):\n")
            if x == "y":
                return True
            else:
                return False
while try_again:
    try_again = game()
```